# No module named 'stable_baselines3.evaluation'

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am have trying to learn more about reinforcement learning algorithms, whilst applying them at the same time. I am following steps to build my environment and model using this link https://blog.paperspace.com/projects-with-reinforcement-learning/ . However, when I try and run the following command:

```
from stable_baselines3.evaluation import evaluate_policy
```

I get the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stable_baselines3.evaluation'

my current code looks like this:

```
  !apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg freeglut3-dev xvfb  # For visualization
  !pip install "stable-baselines3[extra]>=2.0.0a4

  import gym 
  import os
  from stable_baselines3 import PPO
  from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
  from stable_baselines3.evaluation import evaluate_policy
```

Please do let me know if you have any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy
```